# Result must have non-zero length?

Tags: r, subset, dt

I was asked to do the coding project for a job as an intern in a company but I wasnt able to complete it. However I didn't get the job I wanted to just complete the thing . The error that arrives is:

> Error :Result must have length 12813, not 0

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
stock<-read.csv("thafinal2.0.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
dateInput(inputId = 'date1',label = 'Start',value = "2017-08-20"),
dateInput(inputId = 'date2',label = 'Stop',value = "2018-08-20"),
tabPanel("stock", DT::dataTableOutput("table")))
server <- function(input, output) {
output$table<-DT::renderDataTable({
stock %>%
filter(stock$date >= "2018-01-05" & stock$date <= "2018-01-03")
stock })}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to select data with in a range that I want.

Comment: Please provide enough information for someone else to try your code and get the same error as you. Specifically please provide a small but sufficient sample of `thafinal2.0.csv` and adjust your error message if this small file causes it to change.

Comment: It's probably pretty hard to find data that had a date both later than the 5th and simultaneously earlier than the 3rd.

Answer (score 3):

Answer goes out to Dason.
The problem is in code:

```
filter(stock$date >= "2018-01-05" & stock$date <= "2018-01-03")
```

You filter simultanously dates later than "2018-01-05" and earlier than "2018-01-03" this kind of operation results to empty set with length 0.

If you change to:

```
filter(stock$date <= "2018-01-05" & stock$date >= "2018-01-03")
```

It should work OK.