# Error while filtering values in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

```
Sample data(dd1)
"d" "sumMLE" "sumB" "n" "p_wj" "p_wj_log" "Omega_NB" "Omega_MLE"
"1" 1 -5.20994142259661 -5.14443748338538 1 0.666666666666667 -0.405465108108164 -5.54990259149355 -5.61540653070477
"2" 2 -6.5962357837165 -6.06072821525954 1 0.666666666666667 -0.405465108108164 -6.46619332336771 -7.00170089182467
"3" 3 -1.67397643357167 -2.09186406167839 1 0.666666666666667 -0.405465108108164 -2.49732916978656 -2.07944154167984
"4" 1 -5.20994142259661 -5.14443748338538 2 0.333333333333333 -1.09861228866811 -6.24304977205349 -6.30855371126472
"5" 2 -6.5962357837165 -6.06072821525954 2 0.333333333333333 -1.09861228866811 -7.15934050392765 -7.69484807238461
"6" 3 -1.67397643357167 -2.09186406167839 2 0.333333333333333 -1.09861228866811 -3.1904763503465 -2.77258872223978
```

I am trying to run the following code on the above data,but I am facing error particularly at the line commented below as :

```
Error: Result must have length 2, not 6.
```

Code :

```
dd1$p_wj_log <- log(dd1$p_wj)
dd1$Omega_NB<-dd1$sumB+dd1$p_wj_log
dd1$Omega_MLE<-dd1$sumMLE+dd1$p_wj_log
maxMLE<-dd1 %>% group_by(dd1$d) %>% filter(dd1$Omega_MLE == max(dd1$Omega_MLE)) #this line shows error
maxBayesian<-dd1 %>% group_by(dd1$d) %>% filter(dd1$Omega_NB == max(dd1$Omega_NB)) #this line shows error
```

Expected result

```
maxMLE
"d" "sumMLE" "sumB" "n" "p_wj" "p_wj_log" "Omega_NB" "Omega_MLE"
"1" 1 -5.20994142259661 -5.14443748338538 1 0.666666666666667 -0.405465108108164 -5.54990259149355 -5.61540653070477
"2" 2 -6.5962357837165 -6.06072821525954 1 0.666666666666667 -0.405465108108164 -6.46619332336771 -7.00170089182467
"3" 3 -1.67397643357167 -2.09186406167839 1 0.666666666666667 -0.405465108108164 -2.49732916978656 -2.07944154167984


maxBE
"d" "sumMLE" "sumB" "n" "p_wj" "p_wj_log" "Omega_NB" "Omega_MLE"
"1" 1 -5.20994142259661 -5.14443748338538 1 0.666666666666667 -0.405465108108164 -5.54990259149355 -5.61540653070477
"2" 2 -6.5962357837165 -6.06072821525954 1 0.666666666666667 -0.405465108108164 -6.46619332336771 -7.00170089182467
"6" 3 -1.67397643357167 -2.09186406167839 2 0.333333333333333 -1.09861228866811 -3.1904763503465 -2.77258872223978
```

Comment: You should not use `$` while using `dplyr` except in special cases. You can read more via: `vignette("dplyr")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error :Result must have length 12813, not 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903815/error-result-must-have-length-12813-not-0)

Comment: Just get rid of `dd1$` on both instructions. That's it. Vote to close as simple typo.

Comment: how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
maxMLE <- dd1 %>% group_by(d) %>% filter(Omega_MLE == max(Omega_MLE))

maxBayesianb <- dd1 %>% group_by(d) %>% filter(Omega_NB == max(Omega_NB))
```